# How to implement ScrollView in XML with ViewPager and ListView?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, scrollview

When I open the app only the ListView scroll but the sliding image I made didn't scroll up together.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
         android:id="@+id/view_pager"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@color/white"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/oneListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="261dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If put the ScrollView within the upper part of ViewPager my app crashed. 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuW4J.png)

Comment: Have you tried making the ViewPager the child of the ScrollView

Comment: yes. and the app crashed.

Comment: Try add viewpager as headerView of ListView

Answer (score 0):

Using NestedScrollView might work for you. You can use the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/test">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/oneListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/view_pager">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but it doesnt scroll up the image only the listview. like concept of parallax?